# Accessing an int[] inside an ArrayList

Tags: arraylist, int

I'm trying to make a program that reads points (e.g. (2,4), (0,0) ) from a file and tried using ArrayList since I don't know how many many points there will be. However only the last read point seems to get stored. I think only the pointer of nInput[] gets stored and not the actual value hence any subsequent sc.next() only seem to change the existing nInput[] in the ArrayList. 
Ex input file:

-1 2

0 1

0 0 <<< I would get this as the only output

OR

-1 2

0 4

9 9 << This would be the only output

```
int nInput = new int[2];

ArrayList<int[]> aPoints = new ArrayList<int[]>();
while(sc.hasNext()){
nInput[0] = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());

nInput[1] = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());

aPoints.add(nInput);
}
for(int i<0; i<aPoints.size(); i++)
System.out.println(aPoints.get(i)[0]+" "+ aPoints.get(i)[1]);
```

How do I store int[] into an ArrayList?

Comment: Yes, you have to move the initialization of the array into the while loop. But then this still doesn't explain the output...

Comment: By the way : You should add "java" to the tags of your question!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: First I gave pseudocode but I think you need Java code:

(I assume sc as a Scanner object)

```
ArrayList<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();

while(sc.hasNext) {

   int[] array = new int[2];
   array[0] = sc.nextInt();
   array[1] = sc.nextInt();
   list.add(array);

}
```